# Sharepoint 2007 Web Part Exception Handling for Missing DLL references

Tags: sharepoint, dll, exception, reference, web-parts

I know that you can wrap problematic code in a try/catch block to prevent an error from taking out your webpart.  But what can you do for missing references/dlls?  Is there anyway of catching those errors before they blow up your SharePoint page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, catch the [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx).

The text of the error will be **Could not load file or assembly**.